# Submenu inside lightning:buttonMenu component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, slds, lightning-buttonmenu

I have a `lightning:buttonMenu` with a few `lightning:menuItem` and want to display a submenu when hovering over one of the options. Having a hard time understanding how to create a submenu.

Was thinking along the lines to have a `lightning:buttonMenu` nested inside a `lightning:menuItem`.

```
<lightning:buttonMenu>
 <lightning:menuItem label="Testing" onmouseover="{!c.doSomething?}">
   <lightning:buttonMenu aura:id="test">
    <lightning:menuItem label="One"/>
    <lightning:menuItem label="Two"/>
    <lightning:menuItem label="Three"/>
   </lightning:buttonMenu>
 </lightning:menuItem>
</lightning:buttonMenu>
```

Documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:buttonMenu/documentation

Comment: Does the nested `<lightning:buttonMenu>` open on a click of the containing `<lightning:menuItem>`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Maybe you can't have submenus inside `lightning:buttonMenu` because in the documentation hover is not supported. Only attributes it supports are `onFocus` and `onBlur`

Comment: For SLDS - I know it is possible: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/menus/#Submenu-to-Right

Comment: Is not there any solution yet? 
@ItaiShmida I have seen also this, however, I cannot see lightning codes to produce this menu.

Comment: @efirat write your own question and over there I could share my code

Comment: @ItaiShmida I am asking same question. I want to create sub menu underr menu button.

Comment: @efirat If you want me to help - try the SLDS example that I have linked, if it is not working, write a question with the code that you have tried, then I can try to help you with it